# argument automatically generated on onChange event handler

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

I found the `handleChange` "Event Handler" code below on StackOverflow and used it. Everything works fine. Regarding this `handleChange` "Event Handler", my questions are:

1. How does `{target}` become an argument of `handleChange`? Is it default behavior of `onChange` to send the target to the event handler?
2. Why is it necessary to use `{target}`? Why can't one simply use `target`? Is this an example of the `destructuring` feature in `ES6`?

Note to self: the square brackets [] around the property name `target.name` are a new feature in `ES6`, called `computed property names`

---

Constructor

```
this.state = {
  username: "",
};
```

Render

```
username: <input type="text" name="username" value={ this.state.username} onChange={ this.handleChange } />
```

Event Handler

```
handleChange = ({ target }) => {
  this.setState({
    [target.name]: target.value
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `target` is a property on the `event` object. By setting your onClick handler like this, `onChange={ this.handleChange }` you are automatically passing the event object as an argument to the `handleChange`-method.

It is shorthand for writing `onChange={ event => this.handleChange(event) }`

2. Yes, that is an example of the destructuring feature. You are destructuring the `event` argument to extract the `target` property.

> ```
> handleChange = ({ target }) => {
>   this.setState({
>     [target.name]: target.value
>   });
> }
>
> // could also be written as
>
> handleChange = (event) => {
>   this.setState({
>     [event.target.name]: event.target.value
>   });
> }
>
> // or
>
> handleChange = (event) => {
>   const { target } = event;
>   this.setState({
>     [target.name]: target.value
>   });
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> How does {target} become an argument of handleChange? Is it default
>   behavior of onChange to send the target to the event handler?
>   No target is not default argument to onChange, event is.

```
handleChange = ({ target }) => {
  this.setState({
    [target.name]: target.value
  });
}
```

In here you are using destructuring feature of ES6, target = event.target